# CAML query for the last document uploaded by a particular user

Tags: javascript, caml, jsom

I'm trying to write a query using the JSOM to get the last document uploaded to a document library by the current user. The reason I'm doing this is because I have an upload button on a form and need to have a way to get a reference to the document after it's uploaded and display a link to it on the page. So I have this code and it's failing with an "unable to complete this request - undefined" error:

```
//query for the last uploaded item by this user
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('example.com');
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Title'); 
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>1</RowLimit><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Editor" /><Value Type="User">domain\\user</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="False"></OrderBy></Query></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);   
clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, Name)'); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

Am I going about this the right way? Amy I using CAML syntax incorrectly? I'm really new to SharePoint and unsure if this is even the proper way to get a reference to this document. I'm having the user upload it by using the Upload.aspx form in a modal dialog and haven't found a way to just return the document from the modal.

Answer (score 3):

Query should be like below

```
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
<Where>  
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Author"/>
        <Value Type="User">Display Name</Value>
    </Eq>    
</Where>
```

Make sure you are using Display Name and not Domain User Name

Comment: I would suggest considering using `<FieldRef Name="Author" /><Value Type="Integer"><UserID /></Value>` in case some users happen to have the same Display Name.